# How do I make two tables in a 1 to many relationship look like 1 table?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table `Employer` and table `EmployerParam`. Having these two in a 1 to many relationship was a slight misjudgement in the DB design. Nearly every Employer has the same ten unique name-value pairs in the `EmployerParam` table, so every row in that table for one employer should actually have been a column on the `Employer` table. I need to create a facade that, for one employer, makes both tables seem like one table.

Is there any way I can do this, using either EF5, plain old C#, T-SQL, or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an [SQL view](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29).

Comment: I know databases well, and I know a view would be a very good solution, but this would be a pretty messy view, because it would have to have an alias for every row in the `EmployerParams` table.

Comment: @ProfK: I'm not very familiar with C#, but I believe you may be able to create a DynamicObject and override TryGetMember to lazily fetch the EmployerParam on attribute access. Caching previously fetched value as necessary. If performance become an issue, you can also add method to prefetch multiple attributes in one query (ala Django ORM's select_related/prefetch_related). Entity Framework (if that's what you meant by EF5) might also have something similar.

Comment: for someone not familiar with C# that is a very good approach. It is one of my first two, the other just making the entity a dictionary of parameters, with other properties typed as normal. EF itself has nothing to offer in this regard.

Comment: Answer awarded for Lie's second comment, not his original 'SQL View' answer.

Comment: @ProfK: btw, it just crosses my mind that your schema might probably be better implemented in a non-relational database (NoSQL), one that is based on key-value-pairs database or document-oriented database. Relationanal database usually aren't really the best for key value storages.